# how to prevent the console windows to close in ghc app?

Tags: windows, haskell, console, ghc

When my windows console app compiled with ghc going to it's end, the console window instantly closes. That is good sometimes, but not very good when I want to read some text output from it. So, now I adding this ugly code to my app:

```
    main =
       do
        ...HERE IS THE CODE ...

        putStrLn " $$ Every thing have passed well $$ /n Press Enter "
        _ <- getLine
        return ()
```

And this is quite ugly, and more, when some error crashes my app, the console window closes. 
An other way around to run program in 'cmd' console, but it is not comfortable sometimes. Is there any good looking and convenient way for handling program output?

Comment: People don't normally run it from the console?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could just write a trivial shell script like

```
MyApp.exe
PAUSE
```

Save that as `RunIt.cmd` or something, and then double-click that to run the application. It will open a console window, and wait for you to press any key before the window shuts, regardless of what Haskell does.

Comment: Oh, nice idea. It works. And more, I can make it like My App.exe %1 PAUSE to work with parameter.